# Error while running Lua script from redis client

Tags: lua, redis

I have the "Hello World" program in Lua script.
I am trying to call the script from (Chocolatey) Redis client. 
I keep getting this error
(error) ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:1: function argument expected near '.'

**Redis Script:  "hello.lua"**

```
local msg = "Hello, world!"
return msg
```

**Chocolatey Redis Client:**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "D:\hello.lua" 0
```

**Error Message**

```
(error) ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:1: function argument expected near '.'
```

Answer (score 6):

[`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) accepts the **script itself**, not a filename.

Try this:

```
EVAL 'local msg = "Hello, world!" return msg' 0
```

**EDIT:** to execute a script in a file, `redis-cli` provides the `--eval` switch that you can use as follows:

```
redis-cli --eval <path-to-script-file> [key1 [key2] ...] , [arg1 [arg2] ...]
```

I'm not familiar with the Windows fork, but it should be supported by it as well in all likelihood.

In *nix, you can also use the shell to provide the contents of the script to the cli, for example:

```
redis-cli SCRIPT LOAD "$(cat path-to-script-file)"
```

will load the contents in the file to Redis. There should be a similar way for achieving this in Windows but that's outside my current scope ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Itamar. I finally could see the output. I was struggling with it for a long time. Thank you again. Also can you please help me with how to call a lua scipt file from redis client. How can I pass the parameters to the file and accept the values returned from the script file.

Comment: I assume you're using the Windows cli as your client - correct?

Comment: I use the "start redis-server" and "start redis-cli" commands in the Windows cmd to start the Redis Server and Client respectively. They are also command prompts and I try to fetch the data from this client.

Comment: @invincible if you find my answer adequate, please mark it so