# Why does Redis trim trailing whitespace before computing the SHA1 hash of a script?

Tags: redis

Redis allows you to upload Lua scripts via its `SCRIPT LOAD` command, and [its documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval#bandwidth-and-evalsha) says that the returned "SHA-1 hash" can then be invoked via `EVALSHA`.  That much works as expected.

Then I "optimized" part of a deployment process, so that we have a separate program that uploads the Lua scripts.  It generates SHA-1 hashes with the Unix `sha1sum` command, since I had (naively) assumed that Redis actually used SHA-1 of the file as given.  But after doing this, I kept getting `NOSCRIPT` errors when attempting to `EVAL` the scripts in Redis.

**Apparently Redis (I'm using v3.0.6) mutates the script before generating the SHA-1 hash (demonstration below).**

---

Boiling down to the simplest possible test case, I started with this script:

*test.lua:*

```
return nil
```

I made sure the script file was what I think it was, and that the shell (Bash) wasn't doing anything weird with it:

```
$ hexdump -C test.lua
00000000  72 65 74 75 72 6e 20 6e  69 6c 0a                 |return nil.|
0000000b

$ sha1sum test.lua
6f65c1b09395aee959e644fa26d4c6ca6f0d462d  test.lua

$ echo "$(cat test.lua)" | sha1sum
6f65c1b09395aee959e644fa26d4c6ca6f0d462d  -
```

And just to be sure, I compared the SHA-1 hash against an online JavaScript implementation of SHA-1:

```
6F65C1B09395AEE959E644FA26D4C6CA6F0D462D
```

So then I loaded it into Redis:

```
$ redis-cli SCRIPT LOAD "$(cat test.lua)"
"79cefb99366d8809d2e903c5f36f50c2b731913f"
```

In an attempt to guess what Redis might be doing to the script, I also tried the same script with Windows-style CRLF instead of Unix-style LF line feeds, but that didn't match Redis's result either:

```
$ hexdump -C test.lua
00000000  72 65 74 75 72 6e 20 6e  69 6c 0d 0a              |return nil..|
0000000c

$ sha1sum test.lua
98260fd830c34607e437f5e418683c2a644b0d82  test.lua
```

Finally, in exasperation, I tried deleting all of the whitespace, and lo! and behold, the results matched up.

After fiddling a little further, I found that it appears that for some reason, ***the trailing whitespace characters on the last line are removed by Redis***!

As proof, the example below works with either LF or CRLF, interstitially, but fails if you add LF or CRLF to the last line:

```
$ hexdump -C test.lua
00000000  69 66 20 74 72 75 65 20  74 68 65 6e 0a 72 65 74  |if true then.ret|
00000010  75 72 6e 20 6e 69 6c 0a  65 6e 64                 |urn nil.end|
0000001b

$ sha1sum test.lua
ee9d1de0dae159d76a57ecb8e7e8c8c75283ef1d  test.lua

$ redis-cli SCRIPT LOAD "$(cat test.lua)"
ee9d1de0dae159d76a57ecb8e7e8c8c75283ef1d
```

---

**So what gives?  Why is Redis mutating the last line of the script file before computing the file's hash?**

---

**Edit: The solution, courtesy of [mwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021515/mwp), [Itamar Haber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160475/itamar-haber), and a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/674):**

1. This is apparently a Bash issue at heart, and may have something to do with the [mysterious `IFS` shell variable](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html), even though only trailing-newline seems to be affected.
2. Don't use `"$(...)"` to upload the script, even though [StackOverflow recommends that form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224890/error-while-running-lua-script-from-redis-client).
3. Use `redis-cli -x SCRIPT LOAD < script.lua`, which pipes the file via `stdin` to `redis-cli`, avoiding mutation.  The [`-x` flag](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli#getting-input-from-other-programs) tells `redis-cli` to read the next argument from `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, but fortunately there's a solution given [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/674):

```
CHECKSUM=$(redis-cli -x script load < test.lua)
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that if the algorithm ever changes in the future, you'll still get a "correct" checksum.

Comment: If you read above the reffed solution, you'll see that it is the shell's doing, not Redis'.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I read that too, but I couldn't reproduce something that made sense to me on the command line by manipulating IFS.

Comment: The forward-compatibility is a nice benefit, but that technique doesn't work at all if you don't have `redis-cli` because you're building things "offline" for future deployment. But the `-x` flag — to read the file from `stdin` — is the right answer for the scripting commands, so I'll accept this answer. It's a shame Redis's scripting documentation doesn't mention the `-x` flag at all (or that a standard-ish Unix `-` argument doesn't work), since it's far better than the other techniques you can find on the Internet (StackOverflow included).

Comment: You can use any redis instance for that, even the one on developer machine or CI server. Digest will be the same.

Comment: I usually use `EVAL 'return redis.sha1hex("<actual-script") 0` :)